# Efficient plan r2c 1d in FFTW

Tags: c++, performance, fftw

I read, that FFTW plans take a few seconds, so it's better to call it once, and in the for loop call `execute()`. This is my case. But of course, in every loop, the input data are different, but the size is the same, So how can I improve it? Is it better solved with boolean variables or not?

```
fftw_plan my_plan;

in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
v = (double*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);


my_plan =fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N,v,out,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(my_plan);


fftw_destroy_plan(my_plan);
```

Also, this r2c of dft is only forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either re-use the same buffers for each FFT (often you need to copy data to/from the in/out buffers and perhaps convert between integer and floating point anyway) or you can use one of the "many" FFTW plans from the [advanced interface](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Interface.html#Advanced-Interface), using e.g. [fftw_plan_many_dft()](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html#Advanced-Complex-DFTs).

For an inverse FFT you probably want a C2R plan using either of the above methods and use the `FFTW_BACKWARD` flag when creating the plan.

Comment: hmm I think that plan in my case have to take very small time to compute,,,,What exectly in my case do plan? only pre compute co and sine array with N lenght?= the lenght is power of 2.

Comment: Plans can take several seconds to compute if you want the fastest FFT performance.

Comment: I found this: http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html   Once you have created a plan for a certain transform type and parameters, then creating another plan of the same type and parameters, but for different arrays, is fast and shares constant data with the first plan (if it still exists).

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point - create a plan once, then do many FFTs using that plan, then destroy the plan when you're done.